# How to change a UICollectionView image's borderColor dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicolor

I am trying to build a `UICollectionView` that has an image inside each cell with a black borderColor. When the user touches the item I want it to change its borderColor to red and back.
I have achieved this, but it doesn't work at the first touch:

[Video of the problem](https://youtu.be/OSBeKuxuagc), I'm sorry but I don't know how to put videos in StackOverflow.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = myCollectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CategoriesChoosingCell
    if cell.layer.borderColor == UIColor.red.cgColor {
        cell.imgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    } else {
        cell.imgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }
    myCollectionView!.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

This is the code that I created to achieve this.
Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside your model add

```
class Item {
  var isBlack = true // or false 
}
```

Then inside `cellForRowAt`

```
let cell = ///
cell.imgView.layer.borderColor =  items[indexPath.row].isBlack ? UIColor.black.cgColor : UIColor.red.cgColor
```

Then

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    let item = items[indexPath.row]  
    item.isBlack  = !(item.isBlack)   
    myCollectionView!.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

this is useful for multiselection , for single declare a variable in your vc and check whether

```
selectedRow == indexPath.row
```

instead of

```
items[indexPath.row].isBlack
```

Comment: What is "items" in the items[indexPath.row]?

Comment: dataSource array of the table `var arr = [Item]()`

Comment: it gives me an error: Use of unresolved identifier 'items'; did you mean 'Item'?

Comment: I'm not using an UICollectionViewController, but this: class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource

Comment: Do I have to create it by myself? I used:
var myCollectionView: UICollectionView?

myCollectionView?.dataSource = self
        myCollectionView?.delegate = self
then I registered it

Comment: I don't have that array: as I said, it gives me an error

Comment: @Vipera74 you should have a datasource.  Can you post your `cellForItemAt` method?  That will tell us how you're populating the collectionView.

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellid, for: indexPath) as! CategoriesChoosingCell
        cell.label.text = categories[indexPath.row]
        cell.photoButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(named: "invertedDarkColor")?.cgColor
        return cell
    }

Comment: `categories` = `items`

Comment: It’s just an array of String(?)